# SSIS SQL task Query creating error while casting parameters (string to Datetime)

Tags: sql-server, ssis, data-warehouse

I have two parameters of DimDate (both of them are string):

[image: I have two parameters]

My parameters mapping are (both of them are NVARCHAR):

[image: My parameters mapping are]

and my query in DimDate SQL task:

```
WITH DimDateCTE AS
(
    SELECT CAST ( ? AS DateTime) FullDate
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 
        FullDate + 1
    FROM
        DimDateCTE
    WHERE
        FullDate + 1 <= ?
)
INSERT INTO [dbo].[DimDate]
SELECT
    CAST(CONVERT(CHAR(8), CAST(FullDate AS DATETIME), 112) AS INT) AS DateKey,
    FullDate AS FullDateAlternateKey,
    DATEPART(dw, FullDate) AS DayNumberOfWeek,
    DATENAME(dw, FullDate) AS EnglishDayNameOfWeek,
    '' AS SpanishDayNameOfWeek,
    '' AS FrenchDayNameOfWeek,
    DAY(FullDate) AS DayNumberOfMonth,
    DATEPART(dy, FullDate) AS DayNumberOfYear,
    DATEPART(wk, FullDate) AS WeekNumberOfYear,
    DATENAME(mm, FullDate) AS EnglishMonthName,
    '' AS SpanishMonthName,
    '' AS FrenchMonthName,
    MONTH(FullDate) AS MonthNumberOfYear,
    DATEPART(qq, FullDate) AS CalenderQuarter,
    YEAR(FullDate) AS CalenderYear,
    CASE WHEN MONTH(FullDate) >= 1 AND MONTH(FullDate) <=6 THEN 1 ELSE 2 END AS CalendarSemester,
    DATEPART(quarter, FullDate) AS FiscalDate,
    YEAR(FullDate) AS FiscalYear,
    (MONTH(FullDate+3)/4) AS FiscalSemester
FROM
    DimDateCTE
OPTION(MAXRECURSION 0)
GO
```

You can see that I have **two** `?` marks in my query, where `BeginGenerateDate` and `EndGenerateDate` parameter values should be inserted dynamically. The first one should cast from a string to a `DateTime` and the second one should compare with `EndDate`. But when I execute this task it always throws an error in the output which is

> SSIS package "C:\Users\raihan\documents\visual studio
>   2013\Projects\70-463 Implementing
>   Datawarehouses\11-PackageLogic\DimDate.dtsx" starting.
>   Error: 0xC002F210 at Load DimDate, Execute SQL Task: Executing the query "
>     " failed with the following error: "Multiple-step OLE DB operation
>   generated errors. Check each OLE DB status value, if available. No
>   work was done.". Possible failure reasons: Problems with the query,
>   "ResultSet" property not set correctly, parameters not set correctly,
>   or connection not established correctly. Task failed: Load DimDate
>   SSIS package "C:\Users\raihan\documents\visual studio
>   2013\Projects\70-463 Implementing
>   Datawarehouses\11-PackageLogic\DimDate.dtsx" finished: Success.

The following SQL query will work but it does not fulfill my requirements as you can see I can't insert my parameter

```
WITH DimDateCTE AS
(
    SELECT CAST ('2000-01-01' AS DateTime) FullDate
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 
        FullDate + 1
    FROM
        DimDateCTE
    WHERE
        FullDate + 1 <= '2020-12-31'
)
INSERT INTO [dbo].[DimDate]
SELECT
    CAST(CONVERT(CHAR(8), CAST(FullDate AS DATETIME), 112) AS INT) AS DateKey,
    FullDate AS FullDateAlternateKey,
    DATEPART(dw, FullDate) AS DayNumberOfWeek,
    DATENAME(dw, FullDate) AS EnglishDayNameOfWeek,
    '' AS SpanishDayNameOfWeek,
    '' AS FrenchDayNameOfWeek,
    DAY(FullDate) AS DayNumberOfMonth,
    DATEPART(dy, FullDate) AS DayNumberOfYear,
    DATEPART(wk, FullDate) AS WeekNumberOfYear,
    DATENAME(mm, FullDate) AS EnglishMonthName,
    '' AS SpanishMonthName,
    '' AS FrenchMonthName,
    MONTH(FullDate) AS MonthNumberOfYear,
    DATEPART(qq, FullDate) AS CalenderQuarter,
    YEAR(FullDate) AS CalenderYear,
    CASE WHEN MONTH(FullDate) >= 1 AND MONTH(FullDate) <=6 THEN 1 ELSE 2 END AS CalendarSemester,
    DATEPART(quarter, FullDate) AS FiscalDate,
    YEAR(FullDate) AS FiscalYear,
    (MONTH(FullDate+3)/4) AS FiscalSemester
FROM
    DimDateCTE
OPTION(MAXRECURSION 0)
GO
```

My DimDate table structure in SQL Server is:

[image]

I have uploaded my problem video into Youtube [Here is the Link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6HfeYT_WKeY&feature=youtu.be)

Comment: At first glance I don't see a reason why it should fail, but you might try creating a stored proc so that your sql task is simply `EXEC dbo.sp_Insert ?,?` with the parameter names mapped instead of `0,1`.  Other thoughts... pass in a date variable to begin with and remove the `CAST(?` (though that doesn't seem like it should be a problem). Or, try adding variable declaration at the top of your query and then using those variables in your query, ie: `DECLARE @BeginGenerateDate DATE = ?`

Comment: I forgot to mention a Funny thing.. which is, data successfully got inserted into DimDate table But it still gave the error that i mention before.I have upload my problem video into Youtube [here is the Youtube Link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6HfeYT_WKeY&feature=youtu.be) 
I would be very glad if you replay.
Thank you for your kind help so far :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution but still don't know how this is working :D......
Before Using CTE, i have to convert the parameters to `DateTime` and `Date` respectively.

```
DECLARE @startDate DateTime;
SET @startDate = CAST (? AS DateTime);

DECLARE @endDate  Date;
SET @endDate = CAST (? AS Date);
```

Following Code is Working  Fine

```
DECLARE @startDate DateTime;
SET @startDate = CAST (? AS DateTime);

DECLARE @endDate  Date;
SET @endDate = CAST (? AS Date);

WITH DimDateCTE AS
(
    SELECT  @startDate AS FullDate
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 
        FullDate + 1
    FROM
        DimDateCTE
    WHERE
        FullDate + 1 <= @endDate 
)
INSERT INTO [dbo].[DimDate]
SELECT
    CAST(CONVERT(CHAR(8), CAST(FullDate AS DATETIME), 112) AS INT) AS DateKey,
    FullDate AS FullDateAlternateKey,
    DATEPART(dw, FullDate) AS DayNumberOfWeek,
    DATENAME(dw, FullDate) AS EnglishDayNameOfWeek,
    '' AS SpanishDayNameOfWeek,
    '' AS FrenchDayNameOfWeek,
    DAY(FullDate) AS DayNumberOfMonth,
    DATEPART(dy, FullDate) AS DayNumberOfYear,
    DATEPART(wk, FullDate) AS WeekNumberOfYear,
    DATENAME(mm, FullDate) AS EnglishMonthName,
    '' AS SpanishMonthName,
    '' AS FrenchMonthName,
    MONTH(FullDate) AS MonthNumberOfYear,
    DATEPART(qq, FullDate) AS CalenderQuarter,
    YEAR(FullDate) AS CalenderYear,
    CASE WHEN MONTH(FullDate) >= 1 AND MONTH(FullDate) <=6 THEN 1 ELSE 2 END AS CalendarSemester,
    DATEPART(quarter, FullDate) AS FiscalDate,
    YEAR(FullDate) AS FiscalYear,
    (MONTH(FullDate+3)/4) AS FiscalSemester
FROM
    DimDateCTE
OPTION(MAXRECURSION 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

One issue I can spot with this is that your variable values don't appear to contain any quotes around the values - Integration Services is going to substitute those literal values into your query and without quotes what you are going to end up with is:

```
SELECT CAST ( 1/1/2000 AS DateTime) FullDate
UNION ALL
SELECT 
    FullDate + 1
FROM
    DimDateCTE
WHERE
    FullDate + 1 <= 12/31/2020
```

which will error as the date values need to be in single quotes to be treated as a string.

You can either put the quotes in the variable value e.g. store the value '1/1/2000' (including quotes) in the variable, or you can edit your SQL statement to append them to the variable values.

Comment: Sorry i tried both ways, but i dint work
`WITH DimDateCTE AS
(
    SELECT CAST ( '?' AS DateTime) FullDate
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 
        FullDate + 1
    FROM
        DimDateCTE
    WHERE
        FullDate + 1 <= '?'
)`

Comment: Did you see my video, it somehow send data to database but give error every time it finish

Comment: Sorry I can't watch Youtube videos were I am at the moment, but are you sure it's the query that's the problem? Note the error message gives four possible causes: "Problems with the query, "ResultSet" property not set correctly, parameters not set correctly, or connection not established correctly". What are the settings for result set?

Comment: Also check the settings on your destination - if you have set it to batch insert then it could insert some data before encountering an error.

Comment: My query is ok(as i mention in the last part of my question that the hard coded none-dynamic version query works fine). The Problem occurs when i want to use **Parameters** . Currently both of my Parameters are String and the Parameters-Mapping are NVARCHAR. I currently inserting value to my Parameters like this way"12/31/2000"(i mean mm/dd/yyyy)..you can see in the hard-coded version(which is working), the parameter was  inserted this way: '2020-12-31'(yyyy-mm-dd)...Well i have tried Both(mm/dd/yyyy & yyyy-mm-dd), Still getting the error...
and **My "ResultSet" property is currently "None"**

Comment: i have also tried this but still getting error

`DECLARE @startDate NVARCHAR = ?;
DECLARE @endDate NVARCHAR = ?;
DECLARE @startDateX DATETIME = CAST (@startDate AS DateTime);
DECLARE @endDateX DATETIME = CAST (@endDate AS DateTime);

WITH DimDateCTE AS
(
 SELECT CAST @startDateX AS FullDate
 UNION ALL
 SELECT 
  FullDate + 1
 FROM
  DimDateCTE
 WHERE
  FullDate + 1 <= @endDateX
)`

Comment: Even error still occurs if i just want nothing but inserting value to my variables `DECLARE @startDate NVARCHAR = ?;
DECLARE @endDate NVARCHAR = ?;
DECLARE @startDateX DATETIME = CAST (@startDate AS DateTime);
DECLARE @endDateX DATETIME = CAST (@endDate AS DateTime);`

Comment: Something does not letting me to insert the parameter to the variables that i declared. As i mention before both of my parameter in SSIS are "String" and they are Mapped as "NVARCHAR"